# Python import to handle imports

Tags: import, python-2.7

I tried to write a script to handle my imports in Python (I want to avoid doing it via setting an environment variable etc.). The script 'imports.py' looks like this:

```
import re
import os
...
```

After starting python in bash I import the script by:

```
import imports
```

Python does not import anything and there is no error message. Any idea why this happens?

Best regards,
Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import your `imports` module, you still have to call each import within your `imports` module whenever you try to access it.

For example, let's assume you have imported the `re` module which contains `somefunction` in your imports:

**Wrong:**

```
import imports
Var = imports.somefunction()
```

**Right:**

```
import imports 
Var = imports.re.somefunction()
```

However if you are trying to avoid calling the `re` just to you use `somefunction` then you should update your `imports` module

Example: This is what you should do in your `imports` module

```
import re
def Myfunction():
    V = somefunction()
    return V
```

This way you can call Myfunction directly:

```
import imports
Var = imports.Myfunction()
```

right, and it produce the same thing as

```
Var = imports.re.somefunction()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have imported `imports`, which imports `os`, `re`, `...`

That doesn't mean you can access these modules directly in your `__main__`, but that you can access them as

```
imports.os
imports.re
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
from imports import *
```

This will bring all the variables from the module `imports` into your current namespace.

In your case: the variables will be these which refer to the imported modules, so that will work as you'd want it to.

*(It will make your code less clear too; is it that much work to import these modules whenever you need them? People do that.)*